# Google Sheets IMPORTXML issue with ESPN table format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, espn

In A1 I have:
`=IMPORTXML("https://www.espn.com/mens-college-basketball/lines","//tr")`

This works as expected. However, if you go to the above page you will see half the table hidden and will need to click the show more button to view the entire table. How can I import the entire table?

Comment: Where can I see `click the show more button`?

Comment: hey actually today there is not enough games so all are shown. normally its the first 20 then show more needs to be clicked to show the rest... i will update this post tomorrow as there will be a full slate thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood about `click the show more button`. I would like to confirm your update by `i will update this post tomorrow as there will be a full slate`.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether that is a direct solution to your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `This solution doesn't solve the issue but i appreciate the time and effort thank you`, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. I would like to study more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it directly: when `IMPORTXML` fetches the page the data is not on the page yet. It is loaded from the backend only when you click the Show More button. `IMPORTXML` cannot click buttons and load data after that.

Luckily, the data on the page is loaded from a publicly accessible API: https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/fitt/v3/sports/basketball/mens-college-basketball/dailyline?region=us&lang=en&contentorigin=espn&groups=50&limit=20&page=1 . When you click the button, the website loads another page of data from the same API.

To load all data you will need to use a custom Google Apps Script function and use it in the spreadsheet via `=fetchData()`:

```js
function fetchData() {
  let url = "https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/fitt/v3/sports/basketball/mens-college-basketball/dailyline?region=us&lang=en&contentorigin=espn&groups=50&limit=100&page=1";
  const games = [];
  const rows = [];

  while (url) {
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    games.push(...data.dailyLines);
    url = data.pagination.next;
  }

  games.forEach(game => {
    rows.push([
      new Date(game.gameDate),
      "REC (ATS)",
      "LINE",
      "ML",
      "BPI",
    ]);
    rows.push([
      game.awayTeam.team.nickname,
      `${game.awayTeam.record} (${game.awayTeam.ats})`,
      game.awayTeam.line,
      game.awayTeam.moneyLine,
      game.awayTeam.powerIndex,
    ]);
    rows.push([
      game.homeTeam.team.nickname,
      `${game.homeTeam.record} (${game.homeTeam.ats})`,
      game.homeTeam.line,
      game.homeTeam.moneyLine,
      game.homeTeam.powerIndex,
    ]);
  });

  return rows;
}
```

Notes:

1. In the script I have tried to replicate the format that you got via `IMPORTXML`. Still, there are some differences, for example, BPI has more precision and does not have `%` sign. You can compare the data on the screenshot below:

   [image: Comparison of the results]

   Probably, there are more efficient ways to structure the data for your specific use case.
2. This API is not guaranteed to stay available. They can change its format or restricted unauthorized access.
3. This script can be extended to run on schedule or directly from the Google Apps Script editor.