# importxml formula doesnt load web data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

trying to import https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/advanced?LastNGames=5 into sheets.. would anyone mind helping me find a solution

tried this

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/advanced?LastNGames=5","//tr")`

however seems i need to be specific as to what table im looking for which is something im not familiar with. any help or direction would be appreciated.

Im looking to import the TEAM , OFFRTG , DEFRTG , PACE columns

Comment: This page loads data from a server. When `IMPORTXML` accesses the data, it is not there yet.  To fetch the data you will need to identify via browser developer tools the source of the data and use Google Apps Script to pull the data.

Comment: any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: The solution will be similar in principle to this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/77806219/23220956 .  It is not difficult but time consuming, somebody might post a solution for this.

Comment: that was the solution you came up with for me about a month ago.. working great but unfortunately is not something i know how to do by myself... im not even sure where to find the server the data comes from... haha

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping data to Google Sheets from a website that uses JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237688/scraping-data-to-google-sheets-from-a-website-that-uses-javascript)